# C++ passing an object to a thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, object

i have a question about a behaviour i don't quite understand:

i have two variations of c++ code:

```
CreateThread( NULL, 0, ( LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE ) clientThread, ( LPVOID ) connectionSocket, 0, NULL );
```

thread:

```
Client a;
a.clientsocket = connectionSocket;
a.testText()
a.sendSocket();
```

works just fine (sendSocket sends some test data to the socket).

However if i do

```
Client a;
a.clientsocket = connectionSocket;
CreateThread( NULL, 0, ( LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE ) clientThread, ( LPVOID ) &a, 0, NULL );
```

and use
thread:

```
a.testText();
a.sendSocket();
```

only testText() works.

I am a bit confused why that is. I am a hobbyist on C++ though :-)

edit:

added the Client class:

```
class Client
{
public:
    SOCKET clientsocket;

    Client()
{
}
~Client(){}
void displayMessage()
{
        std::cout << "test message client class" << std::endl;
}
int sendSocket()
{
    char *sendbuf = "CLIENT TEST";
    send(clientsocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf),0);
    closesocket(clientsocket);
    return 0;

}
};
```

Comment: What happens when you invoke `a.sendSocket()` the second time around? Is there some sort of an exception or something? Does the application crash?

Comment: no doesn't crash, it just sends no data to the connectionSocket aka. a.clientsocket

Comment: What does `a.clientSocket` look in the debugger? Is it still valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anon <strike>is</strike> might be on the right track that something goes out of scope, but I think that it's the `connectionSocket`. However, you would have to provide more details on what you mean when you say that `a.sendSocket()` doesn't work. Does the application crash? Do you catch an exception? Does the application continue to work, but the `sendSocket()` call didn't result in actually sending something? **What's the actual problem?**

Comment: the application doesn't crash, sendSocket() sends a text message on the connectionSocket. In the first variation it does send it, in the second it doesn't. What i want to do is pass an object to a thread, including the socket as a public var of the object. The reason for that is so that i can instantiate and access the Objects outside the thread.

Comment: It looks like `connectionSocket` is a pointer to an actual socket, so I would recommend that you verify it's not destroyed after you pass it into the thread. You have to ensure that the socket lives long enough for the thread to use it.

Comment: the "actual problem" is that unless i instantiate the object in the thread i cant write to a.clientsocket apparently. I would like to instantiate the object outside the thread. it doesn't send anything (that i could see on the client)

Comment: @user912877 any hints in the debugger? Do the objects look any different in the debugger when you step through the code?

Comment: found the problem thanks to the pointers here, actually both variants i posted are correctly working in theory, i made a mistake somewhere else in my code. sorry for your wasted time :(

Comment: It happens all the time :), glad you found the issue!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that in your main thread the CreateThread succeeds and then then your Client variable, a, goes out of scope and therefore destructed.

Comment: I think that his `connectionSocket` goes out of scope. If it was the client, then `a.testText()` wouldn't work.

Comment: i am passing &a via CreateThread(), and a.testText() works in the Thread. So how does it go out of scope?

Comment: a.sendSocket() used a.clientsocket... shouldnt that be preserved in the Object?

Comment: @user912877 depends what `a.clientsocket` happens to be. If 't s a pointer, then it will point to the address of the client socket and if the client socket gets destroyed/deleted, then it will point to unallocated memory.

Comment: i dont close() the connectionSocket anywhere, so how would it be destroyed/deleted?

Comment: That is exactly what is happening.  Even if it didn't go out of scope, it would probably be overwritten when the next accept() call returns.  Dynamically allocate a and all should be OK. Renaming 'a' to 'ServerClientSocketContext' or something, might be good too.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you pass a connectionSocket and in the second case a pointer to a which is of type Client. Maybe you meant:

```
CreateThread( NULL, 0, ( LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE ) clientThread, ( LPVOID ) a.clientsocket, 0, NULL );
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's the a object that goes out of scope.  The SOCKET is just an int HANDLE value and gets stored in a member of a.  'a' goes out of scope in the thread-creating function as the creating thread runs on, (or is corrupted when the next accept() returns).

Try:

Client a= new Client();

Think 15 times before allocating objects on the stack in multithreaded code, then decide to dynamically allocate.

PS - @Anon got there first - I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

from your client class

```
SOCKET clientsocket;
```

whenever you pass that on into a thread then the SOCKET is going to have the copy constructor called on it. This copy constructor may be undefined or it may be trying to open up a new connection on the same port and causing it to fail.

change it to this:

```
SOCKET* clientsocket;
```

then have it so that whenever you want to do...

```
a.clientsocket = connectionSocket;
```

the variable "connectionSocket" is a pointer and then boom goes the dynamite. When it is not declared as a variable the copy constructor is called and you get a whole new socket than the one you were using before. i think that should help?